# advice needed on `Or` function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if(name == "Lu") or (age == 26):
print("Hello Lu")
elif(name == "lu" or age != 26):
print("Welcome back")

else:
print("Hello")
```

On my understanding about the `or` on the `if` statement, if I did not write "Lu" but write the number 26 it should print "Hello Lu" because from what I've come to understand that if the first variable is false it will then direct to the second variable and if that is true then it will print the code.

However when I run my code and write a different name aside from Lu but write the correct number 26 it doesn't print "Hello Lu" rather it prints the "Welcome back".

Comment: How do you parse input? `26` is **not equal** to `'26'`...

Comment: Where are you writing these numbers?

Comment: Im using a program called pycharm

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as you think it should work for example if you took input from the user and  remembered to typecast `age` to an int since you want to compare it with `26` not `"26"`:

```
name = input("Enter your name:")
age = int(input("Enter your age:"))

if(name == "Lu") or (age == 26):
  print("Hello Lu")
elif(name == "lu" or age != 26):
  print("Welcome back")
else:
  print("Hello")
```

**Example Usage with name something other than `"Lu"` or `"lu"` and `age` equaling `26`:**

```
Enter your name: Ku
Enter your age: 26
Hello Lu
```

As you can see it does not print `"Welcome Back"` but rather `"Hello Lu"` like you thought it should :)

Play around with other inputs [here!](https://repl.it/IJ2q/0)

Comment: You might just want to clarify that you are type casting from a string to an int, more newbee friendly ;)

Comment: This is the whole code. I forgot to put the code on the top name=input("enter your name:")
age=input("enter you age:")


if(name == "Lu" or age == 27):
 print("Hello Lu")
elif(name == "lu" or age == 26):
 print("Welcome back")
 
else:
 print("Hello")

Comment: what i want is even if i put the wrong name but typed in 26 it will still show up as "Hello Lu" however when I type 26 it show "Welcome back" instead even if I put in the code that 26 should be exactly equal to 26

Comment: @shash678  it worked. thanks. all i needed to do was make the number into and integer. Thank you very much

Comment: my pleasure but it seems like the important part was the part given by @DamianChrzanowski

Comment: yeah. now i understand why my code didnt work. thanks to the both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You should you be checking for a string `or (age == '26')` unless age has been converted from a string input to a number.

Comment: should i make the number 26 into an integer for it to work?

Comment: You only need to convert it into a number if you intend to do some kind of mathematical operation on it. If you only want to check what they typed in then a string is fine. Note that converting a user-entered string to a number might result in an error if they type in something like 'Twenty Six'